# surface integral help

Tags: calculus, analysis

I tried to solve this test question. I dont know if I have to use arc length any help would be appreciate please

A water fountain sprays water so that when it falls, its height above the water surface is given by $h(t) = 4 - \frac{t^2}{4}$ in meters. Find the distance the water travels from when it leaves the fountain at t=0 to when it hits the water surface.

i dont knwow if i should integrate from 0 to infinity.

Comment: IF I understand the question correctly, at t=0 the water is sprayed  from 4 meters (as h(0)=4) and, since h(4)=0, the water hits the surface at t=4. Right? So the arc-lenght from 0 to 4 should give the answer.

Comment: The integral you need to solve this question is *not a surface* integral, as can be seen in the existing answer. Please modify the title to reflect this fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arc length of a graph is given by:

[image: arc length of a graph]

So for example the arc length of a normal parabola from -1 to 1 is: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sqrt%281%2B%282x%29%5E2%29+%28x%2C-1%2C1%29

Answer (score 1):

In reality, there is not enough information to solve the problem; in order to determine the total distance traveled by a drop of water, one needs the initial velocity of the water.

If you have this information, then this is how you would proceed:

$$x(t) = v_0 t$$

$$y(t) = h - \frac{1}{2} g t^2$$

where $v_)$ is the initial velocity of the water in the horizontal, $h$ the initial height, and $g$ the acceleration due to gravity.  (The equation given has this setup, although I wonder about the scaling of the acceleration term.)

The total distance traveled is the arc length of the parabola followed by a water drop until it hits the ground, i.e. at $t=\sqrt{2 h/g}$:

$$\begin{align}s &= \int_0^{\sqrt{2 h/g}} dt\: \sqrt{x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2}\\ &= \int_0^{\sqrt{2 h/g}} dt\: \sqrt{v_0^2 + g^2 t^2} \end{align}$$

I leave it to the reader to take it from here; as a final result, I get

$$s=\sqrt{\frac{h}{2 g}} \sqrt{v_0^2+2 g h} + \frac{v_0^2}{2 g} \log{\left(\sqrt{\frac{2 g h}{v_0^2}}+\sqrt{1+\frac{2 g h}{v_0^2}}\right)}$$